# Python CRUD instance functions crashing pyqt5 GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a simple CRUD program and am needing to convert it into a GUI. 
My crud functions have previously worked with no issues but when calling them after removing the same items in the qtableview the software crashes. 
I can successfully create a new record object, add it to the tablewidget, my in-memory array and also update my databse.
I can delete from the qtableview using indexes from QTableWidget.currentRow() but I cannot use the same index to delete the record from my database using my delete function, I can edit a specific field using QTableWidget.currentRow() and QTableWidget.currentColumn() but cannot use the same values to delete the data from my in-memory list or my database.

My list loads the data but when trying to perform any of my crud methods the application stops.

**LayoutManager.py**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlite3
import csv
import CheeseRecord


class ListManager:
    """ ListManagement class to perform function on the list of records """
    cheese_list = []
    target_database = 'database.sqlite'
    cheese_frame = pd.DataFrame

    def __init__(self, csv_location, database_location):

        self.csv_location = csv_location
        self.database_location = database_location
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(database_location)

    """ constructor """

    def csv_to_dataframe(self):
        """ Function to parse csv file for desired columns, stores them in a Pandas Dataframe """
        try:
            self.cheese_frame = pd.read_csv(self.csv_location,
                                            usecols=['CheeseId', 'CheeseNameEn', 'ManufacturerNameEn', 'ManufacturerProvCode',
 'ManufacturingTypeEn', 'WebSiteEn', 'FatContentPercent',
                                                     'MoisturePercent',
                                                     'ParticularitiesEn', 'FlavourEn', 'CharacteristicsEn',
                                                     'RipeningEn',
                                                     'Organic',
                                                     'CategoryTypeEn', 'MilkTypeEn', 'MilkTreatmentTypeEn',
                                                     'RindTypeEn',
                                                     'LastUpdateDate'])
        except IOError as e:
            print(e)

        print("CSV Loaded to Memory and Stored in a Pandas Dataframe")

    def dataframe_to_list(self):
        """ Function to create a list of cheeseRecord objects """

        """ replace pandas null field (nan) with whitespace"""
        self.cheese_frame.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
        """iterate over reach row and create CheeseRecord object using the csv fields """
        for index, rows in self.cheese_frame.iterrows():
            temp_record = CheeseRecord.CheeseRecord(rows[0], rows[1], rows[2], rows[3], rows[4], rows[5], rows[6],
                                                    rows[7],
                                                    rows[8],
                                                    rows[9], rows[10], rows[11], rows[12], rows[13], rows[14], rows[15],
                                                    rows[16],
                                                    rows[17])
            self.cheese_list.append(temp_record)
            """add newly created record to the list"""
        print("Pandas DataFrame converted to List of CheeseRecord Objects")

    def dataframe_to_database_table(self):
        """function to dump the pandas dataframe into a table in my database, if the table already exists overwrite it"""
        self.cheese_frame.to_sql(name='cheeseData', con=self.conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
        print("Database Created")

    def add_record(self, cheese_record):
        """function to add a record"""
        """first add to list in memory"""
        self.cheese_list.append(cheese_record)
        print("record added to end of list")
        """then add to database table"""
        self.add_database_record(cheese_record)

    def return_list_object(self):
        return self

    def new_record(self, Cheese_id, CheeseNameEn, ManufacturerNameEn,
                   ManufacturerProvCode, ManufacturingTypeEn, WebSiteEn,
                   FatContentPercent, MoisturePercent, ParticularitiesEn, FlavourEn,
                   CharacteristicsEn, RipeningEn, Organic, CategoryTypeEn,
                   MilkTypeEn, MilkTreatmentTypeEn, RindTypeEn,
                   LastUpdateDate):
        return CheeseRecord.CheeseRecord(Cheese_id, CheeseNameEn, ManufacturerNameEn,
                                         ManufacturerProvCode, ManufacturingTypeEn, WebSiteEn,
                                         FatContentPercent, MoisturePercent, ParticularitiesEn, FlavourEn,
                                         CharacteristicsEn, RipeningEn, Organic, CategoryTypeEn,
                                         MilkTypeEn, MilkTreatmentTypeEn, RindTypeEn,
                                         LastUpdateDate)

    def print_list(self):

        """function to print out list of cheese records"""

        for index in self.cheese_list:
            print(index.convert_to_string())

    def print_at_index(self, index):

        """function to print cheese record at index"""
        print(self.cheese_list[index].convert_to_string())

    def delete_at_index(self, index):

        """function to delete cheese record at index"""
        """first delete from list in memory"""
        self.cheese_list.pop(index)
        print("item at index " + str(index) + " deleted")
        """then delete from database"""
        self.delete_database_record(index)

    def write_to_csv(self):

        """function to write list from memory to data.csv"""
        with open('data.csv', 'w', ) as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(['cheese_id', 'CheeseNameEn', 'ManufacturerNameEn',
                             'ManufacturerProvCode', 'ManufacturingTypeEn', 'WebSiteEn',
                             'FatContentPercent', 'MoisturePercent', 'ParticularitiesEn', 'FlavourEn',
                             'CharacteristicsEn', 'RipeningEn', 'Organic', 'CategoryTypeEn',
                             'MilkTypeEn', 'MilkTreatmentTypeEn', 'RindTypeEn',

                             'LastUpdateDate'])
            for index in self.cheese_list:
                writer.writerow(
                    [str(index.CheeseId), index.CheeseNameEn, index.ManufacturerNameEn, index.ManufacturerProvCode,
                     index.ManufacturingTypeEn, index.WebSiteEn, index.FatContentPercent, index.MoisturePercent,
                     index.ParticularitiesEn, index.FlavourEn, index.CharacteristicsEn, index.RipeningEn, index.Organic,
                     index.CategoryTypeEn, index.MilkTypeEn, index.MilkTreatmentTypeEn, index.RindTypeEn,
                     index.LastUpdateDate])
        print("Dataset written to data.csv\n")

    def edit_at_index(self, index: int, row: int, value: str):
        """function to edit cheese record instance field at index, row"""

        if row == 0:
            self.cheese_list[index].CheeseId = value
        elif row == 1:
            self.cheese_list[index].CheeseNameEn = value
        elif row == 2:
            self.cheese_list[index].ManufacturerNameEn = value
        elif row == 3:
            self.cheese_list[index].ManufacturerProvCode = value
        elif row == 4:
            self.cheese_list[index].ManufacturingTypeEn = value
        elif row == 5:
            self.cheese_list[index].WebSiteEn = value
        elif row == 6:
            self.cheese_list[index].FatContentPercent = value
        elif row == 7:
            self.cheese_list[index].MoisturePercent = value
        elif row == 8:
            self.cheese_list[index].ParticularitiesEn = value
        elif row == 9:
            self.cheese_list[index].FlavourEn = value
        elif row == 10:
            self.cheese_list[index].CharacteristicsEn = value
        elif row == 11:
            self.cheese_list[index].RipeningEn = value
        elif row == 12:
            self.cheese_list[index].Organic = value
        elif row == 13:
            self.cheese_list[index].CategoryTypeEn = value
        elif row == 14:
            self.cheese_list[index].MilkTypeEn = value
        elif row == 15:
            self.cheese_list[index].MilkTreatmentTypeEn = value
        elif row == 16:
            self.cheese_list[index].RindTypeEn = value
        elif row == 17:
            self.cheese_list[index].LastUpdateDate = value
        print("Value Updated\n")
        print(self.cheese_list[index].convert_to_string())

    def add_database_record(self, cheese_record):
        """function to add a new record to the database"""
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        sql_insert_query = '''INSERT INTO cheeseData(CheeseId, CheeseNameEn, ManufacturerNameEn,
                 ManufacturerProvCode, ManufacturingTypeEn, WebSiteEn,
                 FatContentPercent, MoisturePercent, ParticularitiesEn, FlavourEn,
                 CharacteristicsEn, RipeningEn, Organic, CategoryTypeEn,
                 MilkTypeEn, MilkTreatmentTypeEn, RindTypeEn,
                 LastUpdateDate)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
        row_data = (cheese_record.CheeseId, cheese_record.CheeseNameEn, cheese_record.ManufacturerNameEn,
                    cheese_record.ManufacturerProvCode, cheese_record.ManufacturingTypeEn, cheese_record.WebSiteEn,
                    cheese_record.FatContentPercent, cheese_record.MoisturePercent, cheese_record.ParticularitiesEn,
                    cheese_record.FlavourEn, cheese_record.CharacteristicsEn, cheese_record.RipeningEn,
                    cheese_record.Organic, cheese_record.CategoryTypeEn, cheese_record.MilkTypeEn,
                    cheese_record.MilkTreatmentTypeEn, cheese_record.RindTypeEn, cheese_record.LastUpdateDate)
        cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, row_data)
        self.conn.commit()
        cursor.close()

    def delete_database_record(self, index):
        """function to delete a database record at index"""
        delete_cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        delete_cursor.execute('''DELETE from cheeseData where rowid=?''', (index,))
        print("Record deleted at rowid = " + str(index))
        delete_cursor.close()

    def commit_and_close(self):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
        print("Connection Closed")
```

**Main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QLineEdit

import ListManager


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.cheese_list = ListManager.ListManager('canadianCheeseDirectory.csv', 'canadianCheeseDirectory.sqlite')
        self.input_CheeseId = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_CheeseNameEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ManufacturerNameEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ManufacturerProvCode = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ManufacturingTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_WebSiteEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_FatContentPercent = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_MoisturePercent = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ParticularitiesEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_FlavourEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_CharacteristicsEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_RipeningEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_Organic = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_CategoryTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_MilkTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_MilkTreatmentTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_RindTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_LastUpdateDate = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_editInput = QLineEdit(MainWindow)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.delete_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 180, 75, 23))
        self.delete_button.setObjectName("delete_button")
        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(self.deleteRecord)

        self.create_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.create_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 120, 75, 23))
        self.create_button.setObjectName("create_button")
        self.create_button.clicked.connect(self.showDialogAdd)

        self.edit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.edit_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 150, 75, 23))
        self.edit_button.setObjectName("edit_button")
        self.edit_button.clicked.connect(self.showDialogEdit)
        self.close_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.close_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 550, 75, 23))
        self.close_button.setObjectName("close_button")
        self.load_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.load_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 10, 75, 23))
        self.load_button.setObjectName("load_button")
        self.load_button.clicked.connect(self.loadData)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 591))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(19)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.delete_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.create_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create"))
        self.edit_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.close_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))
        self.load_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))

    def loadData(self):

        self.cheese_list.csv_to_dataframe()
        self.cheese_list.dataframe_to_database_table()

        results = self.cheese_list.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM cheeseData")

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(results):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

    def deleteRecord(self):

        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        column = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)




    def createRecord(self):
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.tableWidget.rowCount() + 1)
        tempObject = self.cheese_list.new_record(self.input_CheeseId, self.input_CheeseNameEn,
                                                 self.input_ManufacturerNameEn,
                                                 self.input_ManufacturerProvCode, self.input_ManufacturingTypeEn,
                                                 self.input_WebSiteEn, self.input_FatContentPercent,
                                                 self.input_MoisturePercent, self.input_ParticularitiesEn,
                                                 self.input_FlavourEn, self.input_CharacteristicsEn,
                                                 self.input_RipeningEn, self.input_Organic, self.input_CategoryTypeEn,
                                                 self.input_MilkTypeEn, self.input_MilkTreatmentTypeEn,
                                                 self.input_RindTypeEn, self.input_LastUpdateDate)

        self.cheese_list.add_record(tempObject)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 0,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_CheeseId)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 1,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_CheeseNameEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 2,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_ManufacturerNameEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 3,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_ManufacturerProvCode)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 4,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_ManufacturingTypeEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 5,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_WebSiteEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 6,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_FatContentPercent)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 7,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_MoisturePercent)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 8,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_ParticularitiesEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 9,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_FlavourEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 10,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_CharacteristicsEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 11,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_RipeningEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 12,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_Organic)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 13,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_CategoryTypeEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 14,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_MilkTypeEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 15,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_MilkTreatmentTypeEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 16,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_RindTypeEn)))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, 17,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_LastUpdateDate)))

    def editRecord(self):

        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        column = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column,
                                 QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(self.input_editInput)))


    def showDialogAdd(self):

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog',
                                               'Enter your name:', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_CheeseId = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_CheeseNameEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_ManufacturerNameEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_ManufacturerProvCode = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_ManufacturingTypeEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_WebSiteEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_FatContentPercent = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_MoisturePercent = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_ParticularitiesEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_FlavourEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_CharacteristicsEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_RipeningEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_Organic = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_CategoryTypeEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_MilkTypeEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_MilkTreatmentTypeEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_RindTypeEn = text

        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter your name', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_LastUpdateDate = text

        self.createRecord()

    def showDialogEdit(self):
        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, 'Input Dialog',
                                               'Enter your name:', QLineEdit.Normal)
        if okPressed:
            self.input_editInput = text
            self.editRecord()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

CheeseRecord.py
import csv
    #Sean Di Rienzo

```
class CheeseRecord:
    """ CheeseRecord object """

    def __init__(self, cheese_id, CheeseNameEn, ManufacturerNameEn,
                 ManufacturerProvCode, ManufacturingTypeEn, WebSiteEn,
                 FatContentPercent, MoisturePercent, ParticularitiesEn, FlavourEn,
                 CharacteristicsEn, RipeningEn, Organic, CategoryTypeEn,
                 MilkTypeEn, MilkTreatmentTypeEn, RindTypeEn,
                 LastUpdateDate):
        """Constructor , taking in parameters for the desired fields from the csv"""

        self.CheeseId = cheese_id
        self.CheeseNameEn = CheeseNameEn
        self.ManufacturerNameEn = ManufacturerNameEn
        self.ManufacturerProvCode = ManufacturerProvCode
        self.ManufacturingTypeEn = ManufacturingTypeEn
        self.WebSiteEn = WebSiteEn
        self.FatContentPercent = FatContentPercent
        self.MoisturePercent = MoisturePercent
        self.ParticularitiesEn = ParticularitiesEn
        self.FlavourEn = FlavourEn
        self.CharacteristicsEn = CharacteristicsEn
        self.RipeningEn = RipeningEn
        self.Organic = Organic
        self.CategoryTypeEn = CategoryTypeEn
        self.MilkTypeEn = MilkTypeEn
        self.MilkTreatmentTypeEn = MilkTreatmentTypeEn
        self.RindTypeEn = RindTypeEn
        self.LastUpdateDate = LastUpdateDate



    def convert_to_string(self):
        """ Returns a string with the CheeseObject's data """
        cheese_record_string = " "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.CheeseId) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.CheeseNameEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.ManufacturerNameEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.ManufacturerProvCode) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.ManufacturingTypeEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.WebSiteEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.FatContentPercent) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.MoisturePercent) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.ParticularitiesEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.FlavourEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.CharacteristicsEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.RipeningEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.Organic) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.CategoryTypeEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.MilkTypeEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.MilkTreatmentTypeEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.RindTypeEn) + " | "
        cheese_record_string += str(self.LastUpdateDate)

        return cheese_record_string
```

Comment: even my print_at_index() function causes the program to crash

Comment: share the .csv and .sqlite, what is `CheeseRecord`? provide a [mre]

Comment: the .csv is the original data  that I have to work with. I use pandas to store it in a dataframe and then create an sqlite database from it, it's not really important for what is causing me troubles. CheeseRecord is an class that represents a single cheeseRecord object with 18 instance fields. An array of cheeserecord objects is kept in memory and I'm trying to keep it at parity the the database file.

Comment: I need everything you need to reproduce your code, if you want help provide it. If there are irrelevant elements then remove it from your code but keep it reproducible.

Comment: for some reason when I call the instance functions  from my ListManager object in main the program just quits out. all of these functions have been tested previously working with an if / elsif command line utility, I'm just trying to get it working with a gui

Comment: mmm, I can not help but provide me with everything I asked for, I am not a wizard who will get the magic answer from the hat. Let me know when you provide it, bye.

Comment: I will upload them to a pastebin to make it all fit.

Command Line interface - https://pastebin.com/EFwrDdjJ
GUI main - https://pastebin.com/L2jpBkGJ
CheeseRecord class -https://pastebin.com/8apJ4deL
ListManager - https://pastebin.com/9f0CWxLh

Comment: share the .csv...

Comment: https://filebin.net/fhid4pdv5owlb8p5

Answer (score 0):

You have the following errors:

- You use names to assign a different value for which it was created, for example input_CheeseId is a QLineEdit but then use input_CheeseId to store a text, and on a next occasion you want to get the text of the QLineEdit using input_CheeseId but this is already a text generating the error.
- Another more trivial error is that PyQt recommends not modifying the class generated by Qt Designer but creating a class that inherits from the appropriate widget and using the initial class to fill in the widget(see [this](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code) for more info).

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QLineEdit

import ListManager


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.input_CheeseId = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_CheeseNameEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ManufacturerNameEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ManufacturerProvCode = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ManufacturingTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_WebSiteEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_FatContentPercent = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_MoisturePercent = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_ParticularitiesEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_FlavourEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_CharacteristicsEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_RipeningEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_Organic = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_CategoryTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_MilkTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_MilkTreatmentTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_RindTypeEn = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_LastUpdateDate = QLineEdit(MainWindow)
        self.input_editInput = QLineEdit(MainWindow)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.delete_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 180, 75, 23))
        self.delete_button.setObjectName("delete_button")

        self.create_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.create_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 120, 75, 23))
        self.create_button.setObjectName("create_button")

        self.edit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.edit_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 150, 75, 23))
        self.edit_button.setObjectName("edit_button")
        self.close_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.close_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 550, 75, 23))
        self.close_button.setObjectName("close_button")
        self.load_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.load_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 10, 75, 23))
        self.load_button.setObjectName("load_button")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 591))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(19)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.delete_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.create_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create"))
        self.edit_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.close_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))
        self.load_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, names, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.line_edits = []

        scrollarea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollarea.setWidget(widget)
        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(widget)

        for name in names:
            le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            flay.addRow(name, le)
            self.line_edits.append(le)

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()
        buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok
        )

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlay.addWidget(scrollarea)
        vlay.addWidget(buttonBox)

        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def get_results(self):
        return [le.text() for le in self.line_edits]


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cheese_list = ListManager.ListManager(
            "canadianCheeseDirectory.csv", "canadianCheeseDirectory.sqlite"
        )
        self.load_button.clicked.connect(self.loadData)
        self.edit_button.clicked.connect(self.showDialogEdit)
        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(self.deleteRecord)
        self.create_button.clicked.connect(self.showDialogAdd)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def loadData(self):
        self.cheese_list.csv_to_dataframe()
        self.cheese_list.dataframe_to_database_table()
        results = self.cheese_list.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM cheeseData")
        self.tableWidget.clear()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list(self.cheese_list.cheese_frame))
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(results):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(
                    row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data))
                )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def deleteRecord(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        column = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        self.tableWidget.removeRow(row)

    def createRecord(self, values):
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.tableWidget.rowCount() + 1)
        tempObject = self.cheese_list.new_record(*values)

        self.cheese_list.add_record(tempObject)

        for i, value in enumerate(values):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(
                self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, i, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(value)
            )

    def editRecord(self, text):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        column = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def showDialogAdd(self):
        dialog = Dialog(list(self.cheese_list.cheese_frame), self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            values = dialog.get_results()
            self.createRecord(values)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def showDialogEdit(self):
        text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(
            self, "Input Dialog", "Enter your name:", QLineEdit.Normal
        )
        if okPressed:
            self.editRecord(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```